# Voice command in non-english Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, voice-command

Is there a good software to add voice command to my Windows 7 machine?
English voice command would work for me, but I am unable to get it via OS both because I use a pt-BR Windows 7, and becuse I only have the Home Premium version. Upgrading is too expensive for me.

Do you recommend a good alternative. It could be either free or paid, as long it's good.